# enumerating sublists that contain strings and integers (python)

Tags: python, enumeration, nested-lists

Here is an example of my list.
I would like to enumerate each nested list in this list and still be able to print the list of lists in the same format.
after I enumerate these nested lists i would also like to index by the enumerations, in order to search through the master list by number.
is this possible?

```
weaponstore = [['Slingshot', 5, 20],['Leather Sandals', 5, 40],['Wooden Sword', 15, 100]]
```

I want to enumerate the list 'weaponstore' so that afterward it would be:

```
weaponstore = [[0, 'Slingshot', 5, 20],[1,'Leather Sandals', 5, 40],[2,'Wooden Sword', 15, 100]]
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, what is wrong with `print weaponstore`. You can look at `enumerate()` if you need an index while you enumerate. But you will need to provide more context for any additional help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "enumerate" in this context, and I especially don't know what you mean by "index by the enumerations."

Comment: Why do you need to insert the index into the sublist, you can already access the sublist via an index, e.g. `weaponstore[0]`.

Comment: for easier user access, so when weaponstore contains 50 nested lists, they can simply type the number corresponding to the one they want, instead of counting them all, or adding another function for searching.

Comment: But `weaponstore[10]` would already give them direct access to the 11th item in the list. Adding in the index into the sublist doesn't give them any new way to access the list.

Comment: but they would not be able to know what weaponstore[10] actually was without counting to it. which is kind of annoying in my opinon.

Comment: Adding the index to the list doesn't help that (how would they know the index without iterating to it)... you might need to look into another data structure like a `dict`, e.g. `weaponstore['Slingshot']` would give them direct access to Slingshot details.

Comment: well it does if the list is printed.. then they can see the contents of all the sublists and the numbers...
using this line:
print '\n'.join('{} {} {}'.format(*location) for location in armorstore)
i didn't ask to give the details of the list since these are already provided. just trying to get it so i can type '1' instead of 'Slingshot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no benefit to storing an item's index inside the item. It looks like you might just want to print the weapon store as a numbered list so that the user can more easily choose the one they want. Instead of putting the index into each item, you should just display it without changing your data structure:

```
>>> weaponstore = [['Slingshot', 5, 20],['Leather Sandals', 5, 40],['Wooden Sword', 15, 100]]
>>> for idx,item in enumerate(weaponstore):
...     print('#{}: {}\nQuantity: {}\nCost: {}'.format(idx, *item))
...
#0: Slingshot
Quantity: 5
Cost: 20
#1: Leather Sandals
Quantity: 5
Cost: 40
#2: Wooden Sword
Quantity: 15
Cost: 100
```

This loops over `weaponstore` with the proper index tacked onto each item. For each item, it will print a formatted string that inserts the passed arguments into the curly brackets.

You might want to use `.format(idx+1, ...` instead of just `idx`, so that the list starts with the more natural `1`. You would then subtract `1` from whatever number the user enters to determine which item they want.

Comment: @Joe - If this answer solved your issue, you can indicate as much by clicking the check mark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

Using comprehension and `enumerate`. (Creates a new list.)

```
[[i] + l for i, l in enumerate(weaponstore)]
```

Or inplace. (Modifies weaponstore.)

```
for i, l in enumerate(weaponstore):
    l.insert(0, i)
```

Comment: This does not seem to actually enumerate the list..
although it does not give an error

Comment: @Joe what do you mean by enumerate the list?

Comment: Your second answer works perfectly but the first one does not. not sure why.

Comment: The first creates a new list.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Using python list comprehension.

```
>>> [[i] +j for i, j in enumerate(weaponstore)]
[[0, 'Slingshot', 5, 20], [1, 'Leather Sandals', 5, 40], [2, 'Wooden Sword', 15, 100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a means of getting from an identifier to the weapon in the weaponstore then you should look into a dict:

```
weaponstore = {
    id1: ['Slingshot', 5, 20],
    id2: ['Leather Sandals', 5, 40],
    id3: ['Wooden Sword', 15, 100]
}
```

Which would allow access:

```
weaponstore[id1]   # once they know what the id is
```

Now you could use there initial positions in the original list as their id, but this is quite fragile and prone to breaking when you add/remove an item from the store. `id` can be any (hashable) object, so you could use the weapons name as it's id:

```
weaponstore = {
    'Slingshot: [5, 20],
    'Leather Sandals': [5, 40],
    'Wooden Sword': [15, 100]
}
```

Now it can be accessed:

```
weaponstore['Slingshot']
```

You could go even further and make the details a dict too:

```
weaponstore = {
    'Slingshot',: {'quantity': 5, 'cost': 20},
    'Leather Sandals': {'quantity': 5, 'cost': 40},
    'Wooden Sword': {'quantity': 15, 'cost': 100}
}

weaponstore['Slingshot]['cost'] == 20
```

You can iterate over the items in the store:

```
for weapon, details in weaponstore.items():
    print(weapon, details)
```

But it's really hard to tell what your needs are from your description